# Indicator7 ( cumulative sum of cases for 7 days) in r data frame

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

[How the dataset looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVgF1.png)

My task is to create this column in R.

A 7 day indicator is the number of cases per 100,000 residents over the last 7 days (including the current date). Create a new numeric variable indicator7 containing this 7 day indicator.

I have a dataframe consisting of date as posixct, cases, and country column for 55000+ observations.

I recently came from MS Excel to R. I don't quite know how to automate this in R. I was asked to use base R commands only, without any external libraries.

```
dput(head(ind7,50))
structure(list(df.date = structure(c(-61665929608, -61697465608, 
-61729001608, -61760537608, -61792160008, -61823696008, -61855232008, 
-61886768008, -61918390408, -61949926408, -61981462408, -62012998408, 
-62044620808, -62076156808, -62107692808, -61163686408, -61195222408, 
-61226758408, -61258294408, -61289916808, -61321452808, -61352988808, 
-61384524808, -61416147208, -61447683208, -61479219208, -61510755208, 
-61542377608, -61573913608, -61605449608, -61636985608, -61668608008, 
-61700144008, -61731680008, -61763216008, -61794838408, -61826374408, 
-61857910408, -61889446408, -61921068808, -61952604808, -61984140808, 
-62015676808, -62047299208, -62078835208, -62110371208, -61197814408, 
-61229350408, -61260886408, -61292508808), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), df.cases = c(205L, 66L, 360L, 146L, 0L, 
224L, 80L, 126L, 58L, 40L, 121L, 86L, 95L, 132L, 76L, 157L, 123L, 
0L, 113L, 199L, 65L, 81L, 61L, 116L, 135L, 88L, 87L, 59L, 68L, 
47L, 0L, 32L, 66L, 129L, 96L, 0L, 10L, 77L, 68L, 62L, 145L, 44L, 
7L, 5L, 17L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 0L, 35L), df.countriesAndTerritories = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", 
"Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua_and_Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", 
"Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", 
"Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", 
"Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba", 
"Bosnia_and_Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British_Virgin_Islands", 
"Brunei_Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina_Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", 
"Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape_Verde", "Cases_on_an_international_conveyance_Japan", 
"Cayman_Islands", "Central_African_Republic", "Chad", "Chile", 
"China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Costa_Rica", "Cote_dIvoire", 
"Croatia", "Cuba", "Curaçao", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo", 
"Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican_Republic", "Ecuador", 
"Egypt", "El_Salvador", "Equatorial_Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", 
"Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Falkland_Islands_(Malvinas)", "Faroe_Islands", 
"Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French_Polynesia", "Gabon", "Gambia", 
"Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", 
"Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea_Bissau", 
"Guyana", "Haiti", "Holy_See", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
"India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle_of_Man", 
"Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", 
"Kenya", "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", 
"Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", 
"Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", 
"Mali", "Malta", "Marshall_Islands", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", 
"Mexico", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", 
"Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", 
"New_Caledonia", "New_Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", 
"North_Macedonia", "Northern_Mariana_Islands", "Norway", "Oman", 
"Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua_New_Guinea", "Paraguay", 
"Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto_Rico", "Qatar", 
"Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint_Kitts_and_Nevis", "Saint_Lucia", 
"Saint_Vincent_and_the_Grenadines", "San_Marino", "Sao_Tome_and_Principe", 
"Saudi_Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra_Leone", 
"Singapore", "Sint_Maarten", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon_Islands", 
"Somalia", "South_Africa", "South_Korea", "South_Sudan", "Spain", 
"Sri_Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", 
"Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Timor_Leste", "Togo", "Trinidad_and_Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turks_and_Caicos_islands", "Uganda", "Ukraine", 
"United_Arab_Emirates", "United_Kingdom", "United_Republic_of_Tanzania", 
"United_States_of_America", "United_States_Virgin_Islands", "Uruguay", 
"Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wallis_and_Futuna", 
"Western_Sahara", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Trisha, in order to help, could you please add the data you are working on? You can use `dput(yourdata)` and paste the output in your question, by editing it.

Comment: You may try with `rollapply` i.e. `library(zoo); rollapply(v1, 7, FUN = cumsum)`

Comment: @Duck, I ran dput and my inside it was the data frame I was working on. The output had too many characters. Is there another way to upload .csv file here?

Comment: Try `dput(head(yourdata, 30))` and you will have the 30 first rows only. If it is still too big, try 20.

Comment: "I was asked to use base R commands only, without any external libraries." Why? It is very tricky to apply a 7-day rolling average per each country without usage of any libraries.

Comment: For that very purpose, to make sure I can still find a way around. Libraries are restricted.

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment. Consider researching and finding the solution on your own to help with future learning.

Comment: You can simply say that this activity is out of your capacity, what's up with homework assignment and future learning?